# Is there a way to compile a Kotlin class to JavaScript using Gradle?

Tags: java, javascript, intellij-idea, gradle, kotlin

I'm building a project using Kotlin Gradle plugin. In general, I'm targeting JVM but it would be very useful to compile a part of the project to JavaScript.

I know it's possible for a project to target JavaScript while building with IntellJ plugin (as described in [Writing Kotlin in the Browser](http://blog.jetbrains.com/kotlin/2013/10/writing-kotlin-in-the-browser/) blog post), but how to do it with gradle? I'm ok with spliting the project into few gradle modules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the following plugin:

```
apply plugin: "kotlin2js"
```

You can also specify additional settings:

```
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.sourceMap = true
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.outputFile = "${projectDir}/web/js/app.js"
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.suppressWarnings = true
compileKotlin2Js.kotlinOptions.verbose = true
```

You can find a complete test project using Gradle to compile to JavaScript [here](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/tree/master/libraries/tools/kotlin-gradle-plugin/src/test/resources/testProject/kotlin2JsProject).

The support for JS compilation in the Gradle plugin is a community contribution, and I frankly don't know how well it works. If you run into any problems, please do report them in the [Kotlin issue tracker](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/KT).

Comment: It looks like there is no way to use it alongside with "normal" kotlin plugin - it defines same tasks. I will have to try splitting the project.

Comment: You can apply it per sub project @atok and use [multiple project build](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html).